# Entity Framework SQL query not returning results

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using an Entity Framework Database first model and I am having problems querying my DB.

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
var ctx = new dbEntities();
var description = ctx.DEPARTMENTs.SqlQuery("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT='FINANCE'");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(description);
```

I can see my table of results for the `DEPARTMENTs` table in the debug log, but for some reason the SQL query is just returning me this in the console rather than executing the query, anybody know why?

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT='FINANCE'
```

Comment: You're basically doing `description.ToString()`, which returns the string representation of the query.

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the query execute against the provider, you have to use any extension derived from `IEnumerable` i.e. `ToList()` or `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`

Now you have to consider few things. What your query might possibly return? A List of data or a single data? Or even if a list of matches found, you want just the single one?

from the syntax of your query I assume you should be doing this:

```
var ctx = new dbEntities();
var dep = ctx.DEPARTMENTs
             .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT='FINANCE'")
             .FirstOrDefault();

if(dep!=null)
{
    var description = department.Description;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also do this(I would prefer):

```
var description = ctx.DEPARTMENTs.Where(s=>s.Department.ToUpper() =="FINANCE")
                     .Select(s=>s.Description)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is good - I like this answer, how can I choose extra parameters in the select statement though, say I want to choose Description and ID

Comment: ohh, very simple, do this `.Select(s=>new{ s.Description, s.ID, s.WhateverElseAvailable})`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var description = ctx.DEPARTMENTs.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT='FINANCE'").ToList();
```

**EDIT:** Raw SQL Queries
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Note that, just as for LINQ queries, the query is not executed until the results are enumerated—in the example above this is done with the call to ToList.

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Object) writes the value of the object's ToString method to the trace listeners in the Listeners collection. [Debug.WriteLine(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response - I am getting the following error though : "The non generic method '...' .SQLQuery(string, params object[]) cannot be used with type arguments

Answer (score 1):

`SqlQuery` returns `DbSqlQuery<TEntity>` object. In your case it is probably `DbSqlQuery<DEPARTMENTs>`. As the documentation says

> Represents a SQL query for entities that is created from a
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext and is executed using the connection from
>   that context.  Instances of this class are obtained from the
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet instance for the entity type. The
>   query is not executed when this object is created; it is executed each
>   time it is enumerated, for example by using foreach.  SQL queries for
>   non-entities are created using the
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database.  See
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbSqlQuery for a non-generic version
>   of this class.

Please note the lines

> The query is not executed when this object is created; it is executed
>   each time it is enumerated, for example by using foreach.

Which means you have to iterate it to get the results.